# Gedit - External Tools specify Current file

Tags: perl, gedit

How do I specify the placeholder for the current in Gedit's manage external tools.

For example if I want this in my external tools what should i use?

```
perl -d:ptkdb my_current_file.pl

pertidy my_current_file.pl
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools) lists a number of environment variables that can be used.

- GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI
- GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
- GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_SCHEME
- GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
- GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
- GEDIT_DOCUMENTS_URI
- GEDIT_DOCUMENTS_PATH

Sounds like you might want GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME.

Comment: the perltidy and debugger work fine. Is there a way to execute the current file in a terminal?          this is what I have but it executes in the bottom bar and then opens a terminal.  gnome-terminal --working-directory=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR & perl $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME